# issue in echo html attribute

Tags: php, html

im trying to added some style attribute in certain conditions to my html input
im using this code

```
if($verrou==true){echo '"style= font-weight: bold; color:#000;" '; echo "disabled"; $verrou=false;}
```

i'm expecting it to output this:

```
"style= font-weight: bold; color:#000;" disabled
```

but what im getting is this

```
"style="font-weight:" bold;="" color:#000;"="" disabled=""
```

i really can't figure out why this is happening and why this code printing me things that are not even in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you are likely having is that the attributes are not formatted correctly in your code - and then if you look at the results in a browser DOM inspector, for instance, the browser will do it's darn best to understand and "fix" the wrong attributes you gave it...

So you should be expecting:

```
style="font-weight: bold; color:#000;" disabled
```

Note the position of the double-quotes... To get this, this code would work:

```
if($verrou==true) {
    echo 'style="font-weight: bold; color:#000;" '; // again, notice the position of the double-quotes
    echo "disabled";
    $verrou=false;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, it helps a lot, i think im too tired to not notice that

Comment: Hey, no worries. We've all been there.